# How do I enable Javascript on AngularJS template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

We have CMS where we create angular template. Some time with that template we need to mix javascript for various reason.

Following is an example

```
<div>
  <h1>one</h1>
    {{new Date().getFullYear()}}
</div>
```

but it does not work.
`new Date().getFullYear()` is an example only but it can be any random javascript.

What's the best practice to enable Javascript in Angular template?

Comment: If you're trying to execute within a template, then you should be using the {{angular}} template tags. You should probably be defining the var in a controller, and injecting it using angular's built in two way data binding. Within the scope define the var: `$scope.today = new Date().getFullYear` and then within your template just add `{{ today }}`. Note: you will need to make sure your controller is defined, and included in the template. Also, you shouldn't be using jQuery with Angular.

Comment: ben, you absolutely can use jQuery with Angular.  Angular includes jqlite within its library, but it will specifically detect if you've loaded jQuery and if you have, it will use the full-blown jQuery instead.  Having said that -- jqlite probably has more then enough functionality.

Comment: Hi @Japanpro - can you provide some more info on what the error is that you're getting?  "it does not work" really doesn't give us enough to go on with...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to create a Date function on scope:

Controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.Date = function() { 
         return new Date();
     });
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
      {{ Date().getFullYear() }}
</div>
```